# proc tabulate exclude missing for only some variables in class statement

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a mothly table where month among others is a class variable

Besides a summary of all months to years  I want a summary up to and including the current moth i.e. in November I want a summary of January to November:

[image: the result i want and what i get]

I Created a variable (kumpama) to tell which observations should be included in this summary variable each month:

[image: the data set I now try to tabulate from]

By using two class statements and setting the missing option for all class variables except the summation variable I hoped to achieve the two summaries I wanted.

```
proc tabulate data=work.TabNRPab out=work.TabNRPab_out (rename= AntLgh_Sum=AntLgh) Format=numx13.;
var AntLgh;
class Huskat2 pabar upplatf2 pabman/preloadfmt missing;
class kumpama;
table (all='All Buildings' huskat2=' ')*(pabar=' ')*(upplatf2='') , (Pabman=' ' all='Year')*(antlgh=' ')*(sum=' ') 
(kumpama='jan-sep')*(AntLgh=' ')*(sum=' ')
/printmiss misstext='.';
format upplatf2 Upplatelseform. Huskat2 $huskat2FT. pabman pabman.;
run;
```

The result is not what I expected. All values outside my target range (January to September) are now omitted. I know that by default an observation that contains a missing value for any class variable is excluded, but I though by using two class statements and apply the missing option to one of them I could come around this. The result and what I intend to do can both be seen in the first Picture since I can only post two links.

Probably I do something wrong or do I misunderstand the usage of the missing option?

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The missing option is doing more-or-less the opposite of what you're trying to do.  What it says is, "if there is a missing value in this variable, do *NOT* exclude the case".  Missing only affects cases (rows): any case with a missing value in a class variable that is not using MISSING option will be excluded entirely.

What I would do here is to create a separate variable for the value you're summing only through September.  Here's an example.

```
data have;
  set sashelp.stocks;
  if date < '01MAR2005'd then volume_pre01mar05 = volume;
run;

proc format;
  picture million(round)
    low-high = ' 000009.9' (mult=0.000001);
quit;
proc tabulate data=have;
  class stock date;
  var volume volume_pre01mar05;
  where year(date)=2005;
  tables  stock,volume*date*sum=' ' volume*sum='Total'*format=million. volume_pre01mar05*sum='Through Feb 05'*format=million.;
run;
```

I have two `volume` variables: one that stores volume for all months, and one that stores volume for Jan-Feb and is missing for other months.  (Missing in a `var` variable does not affect a row being included.)  Then when I want to display the Jan/Feb sum, I tell SAS to sum that variable rather than the main Volume.